# How to handle AuthenticationState in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having a net 7 Wpf app that get's the user claims from an API on login using jwt. The login process is working. But i don't know where i should store the user's information on the Wpf side. In asp.net core I use the `AuthenticationStateProvider` but it seems there is no such option for Wpf.

Anyway here's the current code i have:

```
public partial class MainWindow
    {
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
        private readonly ILogger<MainWindow> _logger;

        public MainWindow(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, ILogger<MainWindow> logger)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        private async void LoginButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            var tokenResponse =
                await client.PostAsJsonAsync("https://localhost:5001/api/login/pos", new LoginCredentials(UsernameTextBox.Text, PasswordBox.Password));

            if (tokenResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                LoginResult loginResult = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<LoginResult>();
                string token = loginResult.Token;
                SetPrincipal(token);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(), "Login failed");
            }
        }

        private void SetPrincipal(string token)
        {
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var jwtToken = tokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(token);

            var claims = jwtToken.Claims;
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
     
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal(principal);
        }
    }
```

I was reading about `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` but I am unsure if that is the correct approach.

Is there a common approach to store and access user information in a net 7 Wpf app or do I have to implement it myself?

Comment: If you're using multiple threads or `async`, `ThreadPrincipal` may not work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a common approach to store and access user information in a net 7 Wpf app or do I have to implement it myself?

If you don't have a requirement to store the information across different instances/runs of your app, you could just store it in a variable somewhere in your application, e.g.:

```
public static class ApplicationService
{
    internal static string Token { get; set; }
}
```

If you use an `IPrincipal` to perform authorization in your app, storing it using the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` property seems like a good approach.